# How to tell if this system is doing simple harmonic motion?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator

> Let there be 2 small bodies of same mass $M$. And they are connected by a spring and they are initially rotated by velocity $V$. So by this the spring expands and contracts. The  force on the block is changing (centrifugal force) as its radius changes.

So as to solve it, I used Lagrangian mechanics. I used variable to be a small change in radius of one block. After plugging everything in, the final equation had acceleration on one side and and a function of $x$ on other. So as SHM satisfies that, $a=(-\omega^2) x$. So that the right side should get independent of $x$, but it does not. So does this mean that it's not SHM?

Comment: Is there a net restoring force that is linear with distance?  That is the requirement for SHM.

Comment: Your title contains "shm". It is not even clear that this is an abbreviation. It could easily by a typo. There is no clue what shm means.

Comment: Unclear. What do you mean "right side should get independent of $x$"? There is explicitly an $x$ in $(-\omega^2)x$.

Comment: @my2cts I have never known shm to mean anything other than *simple harmonic motion* (the tag [tag:harmonic-oscillator] should have helped identify that also)

Comment: @KyleKanos A question should be self contained.

Comment: @my2cts I’d say that SHM & shm are common enough that they are self contained...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not do so, you should probably put the origin of your coordinate system at the center of mass and work with coordinates r and Ɵ.   Then MR = mr and  the motion of one mass will mirror that of the other (with a scale factor). You can concentrate on one of them.  To conserve angular momentum, dƟ/dt will change as r changes.  I'm assuming you are seeking SHM in the radial motion.  Start by finding the mid point between minimum r and maximum r.  Its my understanding that SHM requires that the radial acceleration must be proportional to the displacement from that mid-point.  Keep in mind that the stretch (and force) from the spring depends on the change in both r and R.  Part of that force causes centripetal acceleration (a variable) and the remainder determines the radial acceleration. (Be careful that you do  not confuse angular velocity and angular frequency.)  (Because of the changes in centripetal acceleration, I would not assume that the mid point is the same as the radius that would occur in the absence of radial oscillations.)  With all these complications, it seems probable that the motion is simple harmonic only for very small changes in r.